# Passing a variable's value to a program using VB Script

Tags: windows, vbscript

The code below should copy strNumber's value into clipboard, but it will copy the "strNumber" string into clipboard and not its value, how to fix it

```
Dim strNumber, SH

Set SH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strNumber =Inputbox("Number","Input Required")

SH.Run ".\ClipboardCopy.exe set strNumber"
Set SH = Nothing
```

Comment: Not sure what ClipboardCopy.exe does and takes, but it should be `SH.Run ".\ClipboardCopy.exe set " & strNumber`

Comment: ClipboardCopy.exe is just an example of an application name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PatricK said:

```
Dim strNumber, SH

Set SH = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

strNumber =Inputbox("Number","Input Required")

SH.Run ".\ClipboardCopy.exe set" & strNumber
Set SH = Nothing
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a space after "... set"?

Comment: Thanks For your Answer it is working Now, and Ekkehard.Horner is right, and after set a space is needed...